# Cargar varios controllers o solo los necesarios al momento de recargar la página - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

El tema es el siguiente:

Actualmente tengo un sistema desarrollado con `NodeJS` y `AngularJS`, dentro de este sistema existen *módulos* en donde cada *módulo* tiene 1 o más `controllers` y existen mas de  *módulos*, un promedio de 60 `controllers`.

El problema es que el sistema funciona cargando todos los `controllers` una sola vez y eso lleva un tiempo de carga (para mi excesiva).
Ya que con `AngularJS` no se puede refrescar el navegador al momento de navegar entre el sistema.

Yo pensaba en renderizar todo el sitio dependiendo en el *módulo* que se encuentre y cargar solo esos `controllers` que se utilice, pero al hacer esto se debera refrescar el navegador al momento de movernos en el sitio.

Alguno de ustedes tiene una mejor alternativa?

Aca les dejo la estructura del proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias!

Comment: desconozco como lo desarrollastes, lo que te puedo comentar es que si deben estar todos los contraldores, lo que hacen algunas herramientas como webpack , grunt u otros es cargarlos todos y generar un codigo horroroso("uglify")

Comment: Ahi agregue una imagen, lo que hace es recorrer la carpeta de modulos y cargar los controllers de cada modulo al index.html que es el archivo principal, entonces yo al moverme de: localhost a localhost/modulo1

Ahi se cargan todos los controllers incluso controllers que no se usan en ese modulo, osea controllers del modulo2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dos puntos importantes a tener en consideración:

1- Entorno de desarollo: mientras vas construyendo, modificando y añadiendo modulos/controladores/scripts y muchas más cosas, probablemente también abres tus herramientas client (console), y recargas todos tus *assets* (scripts, css html templates, etc...) (ayuda por una palabra en castellano), a cada carga de página.

Cuando ves una página *normalmente*, todos estos assets estan **cached**, es decir, persisten mientras no resultan cambiados (tus archivos temporales de Internet, pero también a niveles superiores (DNS)). Google "HTML cache" para más información sobre esto.

2- Como dijó [jacknavarow](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/28035/jacknavarow), cuando tu applicación este más o menos estable, empieza a utilizar cualquier **bundle**, para justamente aprovechar el *cache*, aunque tu pirimera visita parezca lenta (sobre todo si haces click rapidamente), todas las siguientes seran casi "immediatas", adémas, tu primera visita siempre será a un *home* relativamente sencillo tal que la página pueda cargar su vista (lo que se ve) primero, y aprovechar rapidamente el tiempo para **cargar absolutamente todo** lo que puedas necesitar luego, sea cuando hagas click en cualquier parte, no sea que tengas que esperar a cargar el icono del carrito (y su javascript) para que aparezca la vista del primer producto sobre el que pinchas, esto solo interesa en la fase de desarollo, por si no estan o estan rotos.